# Visual Studio 2015 Community - Setup failed

Tags: visual-studio

I have been trying to install VS 2015 community the past days, but I keep getting the same error message.

I - Error message

Microsoft.NET Framework 4.6 -
The extended attributes are Inconsistent.

Microsoft Visual Studio Services Hub - 
User Cancelled installation

II- My computer description

Windows 8.1 Pro 
x64-bit
8 GB RAM

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you fix this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

To fix, I turned off windows defender on windows 10. I was installing the enterprise ed at that time. Also, mine was showing up the "extended attributes are inconsistent" error after the permission form pops up.